# Psych doc says «At the mid level is building an AST…» but, how exactly?

Tags: ruby, string, yaml, psych

I have this old code using `Sych` doing :

```
yaml_as "tag:yaml.org,2002:#{self}"
def to_yaml(opts = {})
  YAML::quick_emit(self, opts) do |out|
    out.map(taguri, to_yaml_style) do |map|
      map.add('name', name)
      map.add('address', full_address.upcase) if full_address?
    end
  end
end
```

which outputs something like that :

```
--- !Contact
name: SMOKE OIL
address: |-
  SMOKE OIL
  1 RUE DE LA PAIX
  75002 PARIS
  FRANCE
```

Now, I'm upgrading that old code, going to `Psych` so, I read the doc and did :

```
yaml_as "tag:yaml.org,2002:#{self}"
def encode_with(coder)
  coder['name'] = name
  coder['address'] = full_address.upcase if full_address?
end
```

And that does :

```
--- !Contact
name: SMOKE OIL
address: ! "SMOKE OIL\n1 RUE DE LA PAIX\n75002 PARIS\nFRANCE"
```

It's nice YAML but, it's supposed to be the output of a whois server, and it's way less readable by humans…

So, I went back to the doc, and looked at the second way of doing things, that is, building an AST. Now, unless I'm not seeing something, nothing explains you how to take the AST you built, and plug it in a way Psych.dump(obj) would still work…

I tried doing (without much hope) :

```
a = Psych::Nodes::Scalar(full_address.upcase)
a.style = Psych::Nodes::LITTERAL
coder['address'] = a if full_address?
```

but, obviously, it did not do what I hoped it'd do… I also tried :

```
def encode_with(coder)
  Psych::Nodes::Mapping.new.tap do |map|
    map.children << Psych::Nodes::Scalar.new("name")
    map.children << Psych::Nodes::Scalar.new(name)
    map.children << Psych::Nodes::Scalar.new("address")
    a = Psych::Nodes::Scalar.new(full_address.upcase)
    a.style = 4
    map.children << a
  end
end
```

But, I could not see how to plug it into the coder…

Also, the answer needs to work when doing recursive things, this is a `Contact` objet, but one can ask for a `Domain` which will contain a few contacts and I want it as DRY as possible :-)

So, anyone has a hint on how to do this ?

Comment: You mean Syck, not Sych, as the original library, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create your own AST then you can’t use `Psych.dump`. `Psych.dump` creates its own AST using the Psych defaults. In your case you want to customise the AST creation process.

Looking at the [source of `Psych.dump`](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/v1.3.2/lib/psych.rb#L235-244) you can see it uses a [`Psych::Visitors::YAMLTree`](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/v1.3.2/lib/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb) to create the AST. You can subclass this and customise how it handles your `Contact` class to get the output you want. In particular you need to override the [`accept` method](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/v1.3.2/lib/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb#L71).

Here’s a simple example that just special cases the `Contact` class:

```
class MyYAMLTree < Psych::Visitors::YAMLTree
  def accept target
    return super unless target.is_a? Contact

    @emitter.start_mapping(nil, "tag:yaml.org,2002:#{target.class}", false, Psych::Nodes::Mapping::BLOCK)

    @emitter.scalar 'name', nil, nil, true, false, Psych::Nodes::Scalar::ANY
    @emitter.scalar target.name, nil, nil, true, false, Psych::Nodes::Scalar::ANY

    @emitter.scalar 'address', nil, nil, true, false, Psych::Nodes::Scalar::ANY

    #this is the where we make the address string a literal
    @emitter.scalar target.full_address, nil, nil, true, false, Psych::Nodes::Scalar::LITERAL

    @emitter.end_mapping
  end
end
```

Note that it’s the `Psych::Visitors::YAMLTree` class that calls `encode_with`, this will bypass it altogether for your class.

In order to use this, use something like (this is basically a simplified version of `Psych.dump` using MyYAMLTree):

```
def my_yaml o
  visitor = MyYAMLTree.new
  visitor << o
  visitor.tree.yaml
end
```

This is obviously just a simple example, but hopefully it’ll point you in the right direction.